# Downloading and installing Python via a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am attempting to use PowerShell to download the Python 3 installer from the Python website into a specific directory, then silently run/install the *.exe* file in that same directory and then add the appropriate directory to my system's PATH variable.

So far I have come up with:

```
start cmd /k powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2.exe', 'C:/Tools/python-3.6.2.exe')" &&
c:\Tools\python-3.6.2.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 TargetDir=c:\Tools\Python362 &&
setx path "%PATH%;C:\Tools\Python362\" /M
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. The command window will open, and then immediately quit. I have run each of these commands separately, and when I do so they work. However, when I try to run them sequentially in the same file it does not work. How can I fix this?

Note:
I believe the problem stems from the use of `&&`, because if I use `&` the CMD prompt will persist, and execute. However, this does not help me since I need the second command to execute after the first one has finished or else there isn't any *.exe* file for the second command to run. I am hoping this is just a syntactic error as I am very new to creating batch files and working with the Windows command line.

Comment: When I use -and only the first command runs.

Comment: `start cmd /k powershell` -> `powershell`. Make sure the destination folder already exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do it all in PowerShell, personally.

I'd be tempted to put it in a script, like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()] Param(
    $pythonVersion = "3.6.2"
    $pythonUrl = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$pythonVersion/python-$pythonVersion.exe"
    $pythonDownloadPath = 'C:\Tools\python-$pythonVersion.exe'
    $pythonInstallDir = "C:\Tools\Python$pythonVersion"
)

(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($pythonUrl, $pythonDownloadPath)
& $pythonDownloadPath /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 TargetDir=$pythonInstallDir
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) {
    throw "The python installer at '$pythonDownloadPath' exited with error code '$LASTEXITCODE'"
}
# Set the PATH environment variable for the entire 
# machine (that is, for all users) to include 
# the Python install directory
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "${env:path};${pythonInstallDir}", "Machine")
```

Then you can call the script from cmd.exe like this:

```
powershell.exe -File X:\Path\to\Install-Python.ps1
```

The `Param()` block defines defaults for the Python version, the URL to download it from, the place to save it, and the place to install it to, but it lets you override these options if that ever becomes useful. You might pass those arguments like this:

```
powershell.exe -File X:\Path\to\Install-Python.ps1 -version 3.4.0 -pythonInstallDir X:\Somewhere\Else\Python3.4.0
```

That said, you absolutely can just do a one-liner in pure PowerShell as well. From your description, I don't think you should need to do the `start cmd /k` prefix - you should be able to just call *powershell.exe* directly, like this:

```
powershell -command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.2/python-3.6.2.exe', 'C:/Tools/python-3.6.2.exe'); & c:\Tools\python-3.6.2.exe /quiet InstallAllUsers=1 PrependPath=1 Include_test=0 TargetDir=c:\Tools\Python362; [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', ${env:path} + ';C:\Tools\Python362', 'Machine')"
```

Comment: Hey Micah, thanks for the response. Do you mind explaining to me what the "Machine" parameter does in your SetEnvironmentVariable() function? Also does that function ensure that no deprecation will occur in paths greater than 1024 characters? Thanks again.

Comment: Also, that 1 line powershell command is throwing up several errors, and I have no idea how to debug it. Is there any chance you can try to run it and help me debug it?

Comment: The `Machine` parameter sets a machine-wide environment variable, the same way `setx /M` does. I'll edit that into the answer. Lemme see if I can fix the one-liner errors - sorry bout that.

Comment: Ok, yeah I fixed the one-liner - I wasn't careful enough with my quotes! Lmk if there are any other problems you find.

Comment: Regarding 1024+ character paths: I'm not actually sure whether the APIs I am using would support that or not - if you want to support that, you might need to [change the value in the registry directly and reboot](https://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx#387625). I'd say that's a bit of a pathological case, and apparently not all software will handle it correctly if its longer than 1024 characters (even though apparently a maximum of 2,048 or 32,768 bytes is possible when setting the value in the registry, based on the above link).

Comment: Thank you for all of your feedback. I was able to bang my head against a wall enough times and fix the quotation errors. I'll look into the character path issue.

Comment: The CmdletBinding at the start seems to throw errors for me (PS 5.1)

Answer (score 3):

Do it all in PowerShell, including installing a library.

```
# This is the link to download Python 3.6.7 from Python.org
# See https://www.python.org/downloads/
$pythonUrl = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/python-3.6.7-amd64.exe"

# This is the directory that the exe is downloaded to
$tempDirectory = "C:\temp_provision\"

# Installation Directory
# Some packages look for Python here
$targetDir = "C:\Python36"

# Create the download directory and get the exe file
$pythonNameLoc = $tempDirectory + "python367.exe"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $tempDirectory -Force | Out-Null
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($pythonUrl, $pythonNameLoc)

# These are the silent arguments for the install of Python
# See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html
$Arguments = @()
$Arguments += "/i"
$Arguments += 'InstallAllUsers="1"'
$Arguments += 'TargetDir="' + $targetDir + '"'
$Arguments += 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir="' + $targetDir + '"'
$Arguments += 'AssociateFiles="1"'
$Arguments += 'PrependPath="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_doc="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_debug="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_dev="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_exe="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'InstallLauncherAllUsers="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_lib="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_pip="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_symbols="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_tcltk="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_test="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_tools="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"'
$Arguments += "/passive"

# Install Python
Start-Process $pythonNameLoc -ArgumentList $Arguments -Wait

Function Get-EnvVariableNameList {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    $allEnvVars = Get-ChildItem Env:
    $allEnvNamesArray = $allEnvVars.Name
    $pathEnvNamesList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $pathEnvNamesList.AddRange($allEnvNamesArray)
    return ,$pathEnvNamesList
}


Function Add-EnvVarIfNotPresent {
    Param (
        [string]$variableNameToAdd,
        [string]$variableValueToAdd
    )
    $nameList = Get-EnvVariableNameList
    $alreadyPresentCount = ($nameList | Where{$_ -like $variableNameToAdd}).Count
    if ($alreadyPresentCount -eq 0)
    {
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($variableNameToAdd, $variableValueToAdd, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
            $message = "Enviromental variable added to machine, process and user to include $variableNameToAdd"
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Environmental variable already exists. Consider using a different function to modify it'
    }
    Write-Information $message
}

Function Get-EnvExtensionList {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    $pathExtArray = ($env:PATHEXT).Split("{;}")
    $pathExtList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $pathExtList.AddRange($pathExtArray)
    return ,$pathExtList
}

Function Add-EnvExtension {
    Param (
        [string]$pathExtToAdd
    )
    $pathList = Get-EnvExtensionList
    $alreadyPresentCount = ($pathList | Where{$_ -like $pathToAdd}).Count
    if ($alreadyPresentCount -eq 0)
    {
        $pathList.Add($pathExtToAdd)
        $returnPath = $pathList -join ";"
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('pathext', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('pathext', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('pathext', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
        $message = "Path extension added to machine, process and user paths to include $pathExtToAdd"
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Path extension already exists'
    }
    Write-Information $message
}

Function Get-EnvPathList {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    $pathArray = ($env:PATH).Split("{;}")
    $pathList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    $pathList.AddRange($pathArray)
    return ,$pathList
}

Function Add-EnvPath {
    Param (
        [string]$pathToAdd
    )
    $pathList = Get-EnvPathList
    $alreadyPresentCount = ($pathList | Where{$_ -like $pathToAdd}).Count
    if ($alreadyPresentCount -eq 0)
    {
        $pathList.Add($pathToAdd)
        $returnPath = $pathList -join ";"
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Process)
        [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('path', $returnPath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
        $message = "Path added to machine, process and user paths to include $pathToAdd"
    }
    else
    {
        $message = 'Path already exists'
    }
    Write-Information $message
}

Add-EnvExtension '.PY'
Add-EnvExtension '.PYW'
Add-EnvPath 'C:\Python36\'

# Install a library using Pip
python -m pip install numpy
```

Comment: This seems absolutely MASSIVE. Surely theres a less verbose method to install python3 on windows... this is like 145 lines of code.

Comment: @carlcrott A less verbose method to install Python on a Windows machine involves installing and using the package manager, Chocolatey. Behind the scenes, Chocolatey still uses a very verbose PowerShell approach but at least this way installing Python is exposed to you in a succinct manner.

Comment: Why is "`$Arguments += 'Include_launcher="1"`'" repeated ***seven times*** (a block of six and a block of one)?

Comment: What is the meaning of "`return ,$pathEnvNamesList" `"? To force a list?

Answer (score 1):

```
# Set the version and download URL for Python
$version = "3.9.5"
$url = "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$version/python-$version-amd64.exe"

# Download and install Python
$installPath = "$($env:ProgramFiles)\Python$version"
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile python-$version.exe
Start-Process python-$version.exe -ArgumentList "/quiet", "TargetDir=$installPath" -Wait

# Add Python to the system PATH
$envVariable = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "Machine")
if ($envVariable -notlike "*$installPath*") {
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$envVariable;$installPath", "Machine")
    Write-Host "Added Python to PATH."
}

# Clean up
Remove-Item python-$version.exe
```

Comment: Generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)?

Comment: This answers guarantees that the Python install occurs synchronously thanks to Start-Process -Wait

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I put together for Windows to check the latest Python interpreter version from [endoflife.date/api](https://endoflife.date/api/python.json). Download it on your C: drive and include the Python executable to your user's path:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set url=https://endoflife.date/api/python.json

set "response="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in (`powershell -command "& {(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri '%url%').Content}"`) do set "response=!response!%%i"

set "latest_py_version="
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=}" %%a in ("%response%") do (
    set "object=%%a}"
    for %%x in (!object!) do (
        for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%y in ("%%x") do (
            if "%%~y" == "latest" (
                set "latest_py_version=%%~z"
            )
        )
    )
)

echo %latest_py_version%

REM Set the minimum required Python version
set python_version=%latest_py_version%

REM Check if Python is already installed and if the version is less than python_version
echo Checking if Python %python_version% or greater is already installed...
set "current_version="
where python >nul 2>nul && (
    for /f "tokens=2" %%v in ('python --version 2^>^&1') do set "current_version=%%v"
)
if "%current_version%"=="" (
    echo Python is not installed. Proceeding with installation.
) else (
    if "%current_version%" geq "%python_version%" (
        echo Python %python_version% or greater is already installed. Exiting.
        pause
        exit
    )
)

REM Define the URL and file name of the Python installer
set "url=https://www.python.org/ftp/python/%python_version%/python-%python_version%-amd64.exe"
set "installer=python-%python_version%-amd64.exe"

REM Define the installation directory
set "targetdir=C:\Python%python_version%"

REM Download the Python installer
echo Downloading Python installer...
powershell -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%url%', '%installer%')"

REM Install Python with a spinner animation
echo Installing Python...
start /wait %installer% /quiet /passive TargetDir=%targetdir% Include_test=0 ^
&& (echo Done.) || (echo Failed!)
echo.

REM Add Python to the system PATH
echo Adding Python to the system PATH...
setx PATH "%targetdir%;%PATH%"
if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (
  echo Python has been successfully installed to your system BUT failed to set system PATH. Try running the script as administrator.
  pause
  exit
)
echo Python %python_version% has been successfully installed and added to the system PATH.

REM Cleanup
echo Cleaning up...
del %installer%

echo Done!
pause
```